# Delete from ALL_DB_LINKS

Tags: sql, oracle

i've problem here.

i write a simple (just trying) query for creating database links.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK XXX.US.ORACLE.XXX;
```

after that i wanna delete it. but it said "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
"

how i can delete that data since it is a data dictionary view

Answer (score 2):

i have a solution here.

just use this simple query

```
DROP DATABASE LINK database_link_name;
DROP PUBLIC DATABASE LINK database_link_name;
```

for database_link_name we can see use this query

```
SELECT DB_LINK, USERNAME, HOST FROM ALL_DB_LINKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thou shalt not delete rows from dictionary tables!**

The right way is dropping the db link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8010.htm